# Backup/restore Blob in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

A client accidently deleted some files from a Container in Azure Blob Storage (through a CMS). Is there a way for me to within azure portal manage backup and restore of a container so I can prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create another storage account and copy your container blobs to it. You can use powershell to do it.

code for copy all container/blobs to another storage account:

```
$SourceStorageAccount = "sourceStorageAccount"
$SourceStorageKey = "sourceKey"
$DestStorageAccount = "destStorageAccount"
$DestStorageKey = "destKey"

$SourceStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey
$DestStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $DestStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $DestStorageKey

$containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $SourceStorageContext

foreach($container in $containers) {  
    New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $DestStorageContext -Name $container.name -Permission Off

    $Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -Container $container.name

    #Do the copy of everything
    foreach ($Blob in $Blobs) {
       Write-Output "Moving $Blob.Name"
       Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -SrcContainer $container.name -SrcBlob $Blob.Name `
          -DestContext $DestStorageContext -DestContainer $container.name -DestBlob $Blob.Name
    } 
}
```

code for copy a container to another storage account:

```
$SourceStorageAccount = "sourceStorageAccount"
$SourceStorageKey = "sourceKey"
$DestStorageAccount = "destStorageAccount"
$DestStorageKey = "destKey"

$containerName = 'SourceContainerName'; 

$SourceStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey
$DestStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $DestStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $DestStorageKey

New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $DestStorageContext -Name $containerName -Permission Off

$Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -Container $containerName

#Do the copy of everything
foreach ($Blob in $Blobs) {
   Write-Output "Moving $Blob.Name"
   Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -SrcContainer $containerName -SrcBlob $Blob.Name `
       -DestContext $DestStorageContext -DestContainer $containerName -DestBlob $Blob.Name
}
```

you can aslo backup your container in the same storage account:

```
$StorageAccount = "yourStorageAccount"
$StorageKey = "yourStorageKey"

$SourceContainerName = 'yourContainerName'; 
$DestContainerName = 'yourBackupContainerName';

$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $StorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey

New-AzureStorageContainer -Context $StorageContext -Name $DestContainerName -Permission Off

$Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $StorageContext -Container $SourceContainerName

#Do the copy of everything
foreach ($Blob in $Blobs) {
   Write-Output "Moving $Blob.Name"
   Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob -Context $StorageContext -SrcContainer $SourceContainerName -SrcBlob $Blob.Name `
       -DestContext $StorageContext -DestContainer $DestContainerName -DestBlob $Blob.Name
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy to a diffrent Container on the same account? Also, how would I recover a backup-container to the original container?

Comment: To 1st question, yes, see my updated answer. To 2nd question, I think maybe you have to compare the blobs yourself between the both containers and recover the lost/changed container/blobs manually using Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob command.